# Why are arrays in JSON not uniform?

Tags: arrays, json

I believe that arrays as a data structure is an organized set of items and by definition in JSON it is an ordered set of key:value pairs. I tried to test it out by a simple example.

```
 {
"employees":[{
"Srno":1,
"EmpID":123,
"Name":"John Doe"
 }, 
 {
 "Srno":2,
 "Name":"James Mars"}]
 }
```

The idea was every element in the employees array to have three properties viz. Srno,EmpID and Name.

However, the second element is intentionally left with 2 out 3 properties viz Srno and Name only.

My assumption was that it will not parse. But it **did**.

Then this statement from [JSON.org](http://www.JSON.org) about arrays, in incorrect.

> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Where am I mistaken in understanding about arrays in JSON? Can someone clarify please.

Comment: Why would an array *need* to contain objects of the exact same type?

Comment: why wouldn't it. Isn't that the fundamental definition of an array.If I may draw contrast with any other language than integer array of size 10 means 10 integers. Right?

Comment: Yes but JSON array != array in other languages. Note it says "as an array, **vector, list, or sequence**". The definition given at JSON.org is "an ordered list of values" which is exactly what your snippet is. It is an ordered list, and it contains values (note the absence of the word "type" anywhere).

Comment: (e.g. check out Python lists)

Comment: Why stop with your definition of arrays? There is no concept of uniqueness either (in your example, "Srno" for the second employee could also be 1). And datatypes aren't checked either: "Name" is a string for the employees listed here but could just as well be a number for employee 3.

Comment: Well I actually thought that if, I allot 3 properties for the first element in the array, then rest should follow same. I guess that is not the case...

Comment: Yes, but not only does it not check that there are 3 properties, the 3 properties don't have to have the same names or the same data-types. Conversely, you could duplicate the first node entirely (3 properties with the same names *and* values) and it would be equally valid. It's purely syntax, no semantics.

Comment: Well that answers my doubts. Can you put that in answer, so I can accept it. :)

Comment: One way to have automated validation, while keeping it very flexible, it's JSON schema.
It might makes more sense if you have more then just one file type to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON defines a syntax for exchange of structured data, but doesn't define much in the way of semantics at all.

```
{
"example":[{
"id":1,
"a":123,
"b":"John Doe"
 }, 
 {
 "id":1,
 "a":"ABC",
 "c":"James Mars",
 "d": true
 }]
}
```

The above snippet is perfectly valid JSON. Notice -- in addition to your "concerns" about arrays:

1. There is no way of specifying that ID must be unique.
2. There is no way of specifying that nodes with the same name have the same datatype.

In summary, not only does JSON not require that each node has an identical number of properties, the properties that exist don't have to have the same names or the same data-types.

Conversely, you could duplicate the first node of your example entirely (3 properties with the same names and values) and it would be equally valid. It's purely syntax, no semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is that programming languages should give some sort of parse error given an array where the values are of different type, like in your example. That assumption is VERY wrong.

Sure, you're correct if you're talking about `Java`, `C++` or `C#` for example, but `Perl`, `Python`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, `R`, `JavaScript`, `Smalltalk`, `ActionScript`, `Clojure`, `ColdFusion`, `Common Lisp` (and most other Lisps), `Powershell`, `Dylan`, `Groovy`, `Gambas`, `Matlab`, `io`, `VBScript` and many many more languages would accept an array with objects of different types.

JSON is just like those languages. Nothing weird going on at all.

PS. I would recommend learning a dynamically typed language (one from the list above maybe) to get a wider understanding of programming in general. Just as I would advice all dynamic language-advocates to learn a static one!

Comment: This does add more clarity, but I am bound to accept only one as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: NB JSON isn't a programming langauge, purely a "lightweight data-interchange format" (quote from www.json.org).

Comment: Right @Colin'tHart, although I never said it's language. JSON just "thinks" of arrays in the same ways as those languages do. I should have made that distinction a bit more clear though.